# How to show selected image and its name?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am studying and simply making an user registration form where there are several fields and the user has to upload its profile picture. I use php in order to validate the data before submitting.

After hitting the submit button it validates the data and refreshes the page due to which the filled data is gone. So we use ex. `value="<?php echo $name; ?>"` in the input value in order to preserve the data inserted by the user. It is possible with the simple input types such as text and others but how do we preserve the data of the image and show it in the image container and show the name of the selected image in the input type file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- form -->
<?php
  $nameError = $genderError = $emailError = $mobileError = $imageError = "";
  $name = $gender = $email = $mobile = $image = "";

  $imagePath = $_FILES['image']['name'];

  if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
      $nameError = "Please provide Name";
    } else {
      $name = validateInput($_POST["name"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["gender"])) {
      $genderError = "Please select Gender";
    } else {
      $gender = validateInput($_POST["gender"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
      $emailError = "Please provide Email ID";
    } else {
      $email = validateInput($_POST["email"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["mobile"])) {
      $mobileError = "Please provide Mobile Number";
    } else {
      $mobile = validateInput($_POST["mobile"]);
    }

    if (empty($_POST["image"])) {
      $imageError = "Please provide Image";
    } else {
      $image = validateInput($_POST["image"]);
    }
  }

  function validateInput($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
  }
?>

<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <title></title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/master.css">
  <!-- style -->
  <style media="screen">
    .center {
      text-align: center;
    }

    .required {
      color: #ff0000;
    }

    form {
      margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="center container-fluid" style="margin: 50px;">
    <h1 class="display-1">User Registration</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <!-- name -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">Name</span>
          </div>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
        </div>
        <span class="required"><?php echo $nameError; ?></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">Gender</span>
          </div>
          <select class="form-control" name="gender">
            <option <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender == "") echo "selected" ?> value="">Select your gender</option>
            <option <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender == "1") echo "selected" ?> value="1">Male</option>
            <option <?php if (isset($gender) && $gender == "0") echo "selected" ?> value="0">Female</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <span class="required"><?php echo $genderError; ?></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">Email</span>
          </div>
          <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">
        </div>
        <span class="required"><?php echo $emailError; ?></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
          <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <span class="input-group-text">Mobile</span>
          </div>
          <input class="form-control" minlength="10" maxlength="10" type="tel" name="mobile" value="<?php echo $mobile; ?>">
        </div>
        <span class="required"><?php echo $mobileError; ?></span>
      </div>
      <!-- image container -->
      <div class="form-group" id="image_container" style="display: none;">
        <img src="#" id="selected_image" width="300" height="175">
      </div>
      <?php echo $imagePath; ?>
      <?php
        if (isset($imagePath) && $imagePath != "") {
          echo
          "<script type='text/javascript'>
            document.getElementById('image_container').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('selected_image').src = '" . $imagePath ."';
          </script>";
        }
      ?>
      <!-- image -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" type="file" name="image" onchange="readURL(this)">
        <span class="required"><?php echo $imageError; ?></span>
      </div>
      <!-- submit -->
      <center>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
      <center>
    </form>
  </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function(e) {
        $('#selected_image').attr('src', e.target.result);
      }

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

      document.getElementById("image_container").style.display = "block";
    }
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Please have a look and help and suggest me.

Comment: do you mean that the selected image and name still exist after you submit data?

Comment: Can You be little more specific what you want to achieve

Comment: Actually, as i have saved the name in the variable $name and showing it in the input value in order to preserve the data what the user entered after hitting submit button similarly I want to store the image in a variable and show it in the <img> as well as its name in the choose file input type.

Comment: The image has to be uploaded to the server first so you can show it. The file type input doesn't have a `value` attribute that you can set. There might be javascript out there that can "remember" the upload file name.

Comment: Ok. But how can we store the image to the server before validating all the data? And what if the user while registering leaves the form in the middle? Ex. The user enters his name and other information along with the image. After submitting the data he gets an error that the email is not valid and he leaves the form. Then how are we supposed to delete the image?